# Why missing assembly reference when I add it in Visual Web Developer Express 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-web-developer

I have built a website in Visual Web Developer Express 2008 and it runs all well and good when I run it from the IDE. I have copied all the files over to a server in which I want this website to call home. The Interop.ActiveDs.dll file is in the Bin folder of my website.

Once I start drop the folder in the IIS folder and access it via IE, I get the error:

> The type or namespace name 'ActiveDs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am not understanding this. I am developing on an XP machine and the server is a 2k8 server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your issue is being caused by your included dlls not being transferred to the proper location on the server when you transfer off your developing box. There should be a setting for each dll in your solution that is something like 'copy local' that needs to be set to true. Alternatively, you can build a folder or set of folders to contain all of your custom dlls and upload that to the server manually and reconfigure the project to target the dlls from that file.

Barring that, check the assembly references (in the .csproj file...you can open it in notepad) and make sure they are aimed at the actual location of the file, and not at some random folder floating off on your development box